# Mark nodes as visited in DFS for Word Search

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

This is the word search problem on leetcode. I've provided a picture below that explains it well. My approach consists of a DFS on each letter in the board (by iterating through a double for loop), I'm doing this so my dfs function can start from each letter and I can get all the different words.

I'm marking the nodes as visited by also passing in a boolean array, where the value is changed to true if I've seen that node and changed back to false if it didn't lead to a path. I think this is where I'm messing up. I'm not sure how to properly mark the nodes as visited here, and if I don't then I get an infinite loop.

When I run my program and print out the strings the dfs is building, I don't get all the possible strings. This is what I'm trying to figure out, how to get all the strings.

You can run the code in leetcode as well. Thank you!

[image]

```
class Solution {
    public boolean exist(char[][] board, String word) {
        
        if(board == null || word == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                List<Character> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                tempList.add(board[i][j]);
                boolean[][] tempBoard = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];
                if(wordExists(i, j, word, tempList, board, tempBoard)) {
                    return true;
                } 
                else{
                     tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }   
        return false;
    }
    
    public static boolean wordExists(int sr, int sc, String word, List<Character> list, char[][] board, boolean[][] tempBoard) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Character c : list) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        
        if(word.equals(sb.toString())) {
            return true;
        }
        
        final int[][] SHIFTS = {
            {0,1},
            {1,0},
            {0,-1},
            {-1,0}
        };
        tempBoard[sr][sc] = true;
        for(int[] shift : SHIFTS) {
            int row = sr + shift[0];
            int col = sc + shift[1];
            
            if(isValid(board, row, col, tempBoard)) {
                list.add(board[row][col]);
                
                if(wordExists(row, col, word, list, board, tempBoard)) {
                    return true;
                }
                tempBoard[sr][sc] = false;
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public static boolean isValid(char[][] board, int row, int col, boolean[][] tempBoard) {
        if(row >= 0 && row < board.length && col >= 0 && col < board[row].length && tempBoard[row][col] != true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the given input ? What is the actual output ?

Comment: The program outputs false with the word "ABCCED" when it should output true. Inspecting the words as they're being built I see A
AB
ABC
ABCE
ABCES
ABCESE
ABCESEE
ABCESEED
ABCESEEDA
ABCESEEDAS
ABCESEEDASF
ABCESEEDASFC
ABCESEEDF
ABCESEEDFD
ABCESEEDFDA
ABCESEEDFDAS -- but I don't see it building any string starting with ABCC..not sure why